# In need of help regarding to create and utilize a count variable such that a set of questions only repeats for every 10th household in CommCare

Tags: commcare

I want to go about a CommCare survey such that a set of questions only repeat for every tenth household/household member that opens the form. What functions should I be using to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this across all users of your application but you can do it for each user.

You can create an incrementing counter on the [User Case](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/User+Case) and use that to determine when to show the questions.

Instructions for incrementing a counter can be found here: https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Incrementing+a+counter

---

I would also like to mention that there is a dedicated CommCare user forum here: https://forum.dimagi.com/c/users

Comment: Many thanks for your help, Simon!